# How to set initial values for Django Model Form

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to set initial values for my django model form
but when I try in my views.py:

```
add_contact_form = newContactForm(request.POST, initial={'relation':'Customer'})
```

It doesn't work. If I specify default values in the model they work fine.

Models.py:

```
class contact(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(primary_key=True)
    tel = PhoneField(null=True, blank=True)

    contact_relations = [
    ('Supplier', 'Supplier'),
    ('Customer', 'Customer'),
    ('Other', 'Other'),
    ]

    relation =  models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=contact_relations)
```

Forms.py:

```
class newContactForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = contact
        fields = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'tel',
        'relation',
        ]
        widgets = {
        'relation': forms.RadioSelect(),
        }
```

Views.py:

```
def add_contact_view(request):
    add_contact_form = newContactForm(request.POST, initial={'relation':'Customer'})
    if add_contact_form.is_valid():
        add_contact_form.save()
    else:
        add_contact_form = newContactForm()
    context = {
        "add_contact_form":add_contact_form,
        }
    return render(request, 'contacts/new_contact.html', context)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thats because you are not setting them when the page loads, you are initializing when the form is submitted.

```
def add_contact_view(request):
    add_contact_form = newContactForm(request.POST)
    if add_contact_form.is_valid():
        add_contact_form.save()
    else:
        add_contact_form = newContactForm(initial={'relation':'Customer'})
    context = {
        "add_contact_form":add_contact_form,
        }
    return render(request, 'contacts/new_contact.html', context)
```

Comment: @dpachin if you want you can redirect the user once the form is submitted to some page view using redirect.

Comment: @Raghavendra, Thanks, but I already know that - the code in my question is a very watered-down version of what's in my app. In fact, I have three different views with the expanded version of that form, all with different initial values, hence why I needed it done that way. This is my first Django app, and a first serious coding project for that matter that will actually be used in the real world, so I am still tripping on some basic stuff occasionally, but it's all coming together.